# Do non-abelian group mathematics have any use in the real world math?

Tags: group-theory, mathematics

I know physics uses a lot of non-abelian mathematics (though I cannot wrap my head around a*b does not equal b*a)..

Is there any real world (macro world we live in) uses for non-abelian mathematics?

If so, can someone give me an example?

Comment: Rotations are described by a non-abelian group. This is, of course, completely essential in thousands of practical applications. If a fighter jet did the steps in some rotational maneuver in a totally different order, it might crash.

Comment: Many operations in the real world are non-abelian. If you put your socks on then put your shoes on you get a different result from if you put your shoes on then put your socks on !

Comment: If you go north 1000 miles, and then go east 1000 miles, you'll end up at a different point on the globe than if you'd gone east first.

Answer (score 4):

There are many instances in physics in which non-abelian groups arise, one of which is the rotation group in 3D, $\text{SO}(3)$. This is the group of all roations about the origin in our standard 3D space. To see why this is non-abelian, let's consider some concrete examples. Take a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ denoted by $\vec{v}_0$, $$ \vec{v}_0 = \left( \begin{matrix}
1\\
0 \\
0
\end{matrix}\right)$$. This is simply the unit vector in the $x$ direction. An element of $\text{SO}(3)$ is simply a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^3$. We may represent these rotations as $3\times3$ matrices. For example a rotation through an angle $\theta$ in the $x-y$ plane (or, about the $z$ axis) can be written as 
$$ R_{z}(\theta) = \left( \begin{matrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) & 0\\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)  & 0 \\
0            & 0             & 1
\end{matrix}\right)$$
If we apply this to $\vec{v}$, we see that $$\vec{v}_1= R_{z}(\theta)\vec{v}_0 = \left( \begin{matrix}
\cos(\theta)\\
\sin(\theta) \\
0
\end{matrix}\right)$$

To be concrete, if we say $\theta = \pi/2$, then our new vector is $ \vec{v}_1 = \left( \begin{matrix}
0\\
1 \\
0
\end{matrix}\right)$ which is what we should expect if we rotated the $x$ unit vector $90$ degrees counterclockwise around the $z$ axis. Now let's apply another rotation, say around the $x$ axis. This is denoted by 
$$ R_{x}(\theta) = \left( \begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \cos(\phi)  & -\sin(\phi) \\
0 & \sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi)
\end{matrix}\right)$$

and we get

$$\vec{v}_2= R_{x}(\phi)\vec{v}_1 = R_{x}(\phi)R_{z}(\theta)\vec{v}_0 = \left( \begin{matrix}
0\\
\cos(\phi) \\
\sin(\phi)
\end{matrix}\right)$$

If we again say this rotation was through $\phi = \pi/2$, we end up with $ \vec{v}_2 = \left( \begin{matrix}
0\\
0 \\
1
\end{matrix}\right)$ again as expected. What would have happened if we applied this rotation in the opposite order, i.e. what is $R_{z}(\theta)R_{x}(\phi)\vec{v}_0$? I encourage you to explicitly perform this calculation, but the result is not the same as the $\vec{v}_2$ that we got above.

All of this is to say that $R_{x}(\phi)R_{z}(\theta)\neq R_{z}(\theta)R_{x}(\phi)$. It has to be remembered that group multiplication is not the same and in fact very different than normal multiplication, and should probably be thought of as just an 'operation' to avoid conflating its features with the features of normal multiplication. This exercise gets to the point of when non-abelian groups are useful in physics and the 'real world'. Often times, the order in which we perform some action affects the outcome that we get. Rotating through space, walking on a globe, putting on shoes and socks, etc. All that $a\cdot b \neq b\cdot a$ means is that, when it comes to performing the action represented by  '$\cdot$', order matters.